# Second, third, fourth max value INDEX in matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a large unordered matrix, of which I wanted to get the index of the second highest value.

```
x <- matrix(c(4:7, 2, 1), nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
which.max(x)
```

This gives me four as my index for the maximum value 7. But does anyone know how to get an index for the second, third, or fourth highest?

Comment: Hi, would you like to join the R Public Chat room? :)

Comment: @shirleywu Hi Shirley! Love this delay in response. How can I join this "R Public Chat" room? :)

Comment: on top, you click "chat", and then filter for "R Public" :)